# NSMatrix hidden on 10.7 Lion

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nsmatrix

I have two `NSMatrix` radio controls in different places in my app. I am developing on 10.8, using the 10.8 SDK and targeting 10.7. The matrixes work perfectly on my development computer, but when I test on a Mac running 10.7, neither matrix appears. I've checked the auto-layout struts, I've made sure they aren't set to hidden. They're just not appearing at all.

Comment: I have the same problem just now. Fixed it yet? I find that if I build it on 10.7 it works but the moment I touch the .xib file in xcode in 10.8 it breaks it

Comment: Not yet - our test Mac is away at a conference for a couple of weeks so I won't be able to try anything out until it gets back - I've only got my dev MacBook with 10.8 here.

Comment: I gave up and switched to using normal nsbuttons :D

Comment: I just experienced the same bug. Have you filed this issue with Apple yet?

Comment: Just tried to, but there is a bug with their bug reporting - how ironic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar problem, but in my UI from three NSMatrix radio controls in different places (different views in different xib's) two were displayed correctly on 10.7, one not. I tried different things, in the end I deleted this NSMatrix and placed it again. I unchecked both "Automatically Resizes Cells" and "Auto Calculates Cell Size" in the size inspector. And very important: I checked all auto layout constraints in the whole view and made sure that all objects have vertical/horizontal spacing (between each other) or leading/trailing space to superview constraints, the top object a top space to superview and the bottom object a bottom space to superview constraint. Et voila, it's showing up finally also on 10.7!

Hope you can solve your problem in a similar way. Looks like NSMatrix is acting very diva-like on 10.7 with auto layout!

Comment: This worked a treat - I had to mess about with the constraints a bit as well, but my NSMatrixes are now visible on 10.7 - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable auto layout completely. Uncheck "Use Auto Layout" in the file inspector of the relevant nib. It did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using some of the features of Auto Layout and would rather keep it. I'll try disabling it to see if that helps, but I need a solution that lets me use it.